# database schema for customers

Tags: mysql, database, qsqlquery

Right now I have two tables orders and customers,each order has his customer.Orders table hold details about a order and his customer id.

Customer table hold information about a customer.The thing is that those customers have properties of a natural person because until now I only had natural person owners.

Now I want to add legal entity type of customer but because they will have total  different properties from the actual customers table and also because in the future I want legal entity customer to become more complex I need to make another table for them lets say legal_entity_customers table.

So I will have 3 tables orders,customers(which represent the natural person customer) and legal_entity_customers.The question is how can I make the structure of those 3 tables or add another one if is need to be able to make a single query that returns the order with his customer(which can be natural person from customers table or legal entity from legal_entity_customers table)

Comment: You should ask this question on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can put both natural person customer id and legal_entity_customers id in order table,and while fetching customer ,you can use OR.

Comment: can you give me a simple example of a query that return all information about the order and his customer please?

Comment: some thing like this should work SELECT * FROM Orders a, Natural customer b,Legal Customer c WHERE a.naturalcustid=b.id OR a.legalcustid = c.id

Comment: I don't think is works because is gona return something from both tables,will return the correct owner from one table and in the second table will have no condition because is OR

Comment: I ve tried it and is seem that return the last from Legal Customer even if it hasn't the id = order.CustomerId probably because si an OR with a column he has and a column he hasn't and it return 1 don't why

Comment: can try (a.naturalcustId != null and a.naturalcustid = b.id) OR (a.legalcustId != null and a.legalcustid = c.id)

Comment: still doesn't work it seem that if any of the condition is 1 is select the last row from the other customers table